Metropolis-Hastings in mini-batch setting
I would like to ask the following question : I have seen papers such as Stochastic gradient Langevin dynamics (link) and Stochastic gradient Hamiltonian monte-carlo (link) which could be used to train EBM models (in the log-likelihood context where these methods could be used to estimate the expectation term that requires sampling from the model itself). My question is why can't we use metropolis-hastings in mini-batch settings; like why do we need to iterate over the whole dataset to generate a single sample from the EBM in MH context ?
I highly appreciate your answer.
